# EntityFramework uses its own logic instead of method in Where clause

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I stumbled upon a interesting behavior when using `Compare` in a C# project that uses EntityFramework.

When using a method with the signature `Compare(byte[], byte[])`, EntityFramework does not use this method but does a comparison in the SQL Query.
My expectation is that it should be evaluated locally (and throw an exception based on the configuration)

```
public class MyEntity
{
  ...

  [Required]
  [ConcurrencyCheck]
  public byte[] Timestamp { get; set; }
}


public static int Compare(this byte[] left, byte[] right)
{
  throw new InvalidOperationException("...");
}

byte[] someValue = ...;
MyEntity[] items = context.MyEntities
    .Where(e => e.Timestamp.Compare(someValue) <= 0)
    .ToArray();
```

This code does not throw the exception but does generate a SQL query like this:

```
SELECT .....
FROM [MyEntities] AS [f]
WHERE [f].[Timestamp] <= @__someValue_0
```

When renaming the method this does no longer work and the expected exception is thrown.

This also works when using it directly without an extension method.

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
  public static int Compare(byte[] left, byte[] right)
  {
    throw new InvalidOperationException("...");
  }
}

byte[] someValue = ...;
MyEntity[] items = context.MyEntities
    .Where(e => MyExtensions.Compare(e.Timestamp, someValue) <= 0)
    .ToArray();
```

What is the reason for this behavior? Is there any documentation about it?

Comment: Client side evaluation is [disabled by default starting form ASP.NET Core 3.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval). You can pull all your records in memory and do the comparing/processing there, or try to change your compare function to something that is actually executable in SQL

Comment: Mind that the intended `Compare` method shown in the question is an extension method but your usage is that of an ordinary static method, so it may not be considered by the compiler as you expect. Have you tried `.Where(e => e.Timestamp.Compare(someValue) <= 0)` ? Should give you an error that it cannot be translated to SQL, though. (given, `e.Timestamp` is a `byte[]` )

Comment: _"but your usage is that of an ordinary static method"_ - at least it was before the edit.

Comment: I updated the question. The behavior is the same when using an extension method (as in the updated question) and without using it as an extension method. As soon as renaming the method the client side evaluation exception is thrown (as expected)

Comment: I'd still suspect an unexpected choice of member-resolution. I.e. C#/.Net doesn't get that you mean to use _that_ particular `Compare` method ... which changes as soon as you give it an unambiguous name.

Comment: Maybe try and use your IDE's "take me to implementation" feature. Maybe you'll be surprised?

Comment: The "Go to implementation" took me to the correct method. I added a second example that uses no extension method, but references the method directly. Still the same behavior.

Comment: Look at [User-defined function mapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/user-defined-function-mapping). Probably, there is such mapped function in your code.

Comment: I created a small example in a github repo: https://github.com/Drast1337/ef-compare-sample

Comment: @Drast, we do not need your example to repeat everything again. As mentioned above, you have to use User-Defined function mapping or do comparing on the client side. When EF Core found unknown method in LINQ query - it fails.

Comment: Thats my point, it does not fail when it should. Why?

Comment: Let me check source code. Which EF Core version? Probably they just check name for `Compare` and do not care where is realization.

Comment: I'm confused: why do you *want* it to fail?

Comment: I wanted to know why it works as i expected it to fail :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is how current EF Core provides translation:

If you follow this [link](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/main/src/EFCore.Relational/Query/Internal/ComparisonTranslator.cs#L41-L51), you will find that EF Core translates any `Compare` and `CompareTo` methods with similar signatures.

```cs
if (method.ReturnType == typeof(int))
{
    SqlExpression? left = null;
    SqlExpression? right = null;
    if (method.Name == nameof(string.Compare)
        && arguments.Count == 2
        && arguments[0].Type == arguments[1].Type)
    {
        left = arguments[0];
        right = arguments[1];
    }
    else if (method.Name == nameof(string.CompareTo)
                && arguments.Count == 1
                && instance != null
                && instance.Type == arguments[0].Type)
    {
        left = instance;
        right = arguments[0];
    }
    ...
```